# Actualizar datos sin pisarlos Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Angular y Laravel, necesito actualizar un campo pero que al actualizar este campo no se borre lo que tenia anteriormente. Deduzco que tengo que usar un CONCAT pero estoy intentando con esto y no me guarda nada.

```
$values = $request->except('URLImg');
$data = $request->only('URLImg[]');
if($request->hasFile('URLImg')){
    foreach($request->file("URLImg") as $image)
    {
        $name = Str::random(10).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = 'storage/img/';
        $image->move($path, $name);
        $data[] = $name;
    }
}
$tramite = Tramite::findOrFail($RComunicInter_ID);
$tramite->update(['URLImg' => DB::raw("CONCAT('" . json_encode($data) . "', '')" ) ]);
$tramite->save();
return response()->json($tramite, 201);
```

Comment: Te planteaste hacerlo con un trigger de mysql en vez de laravel? Podrías usar un trigger afterupdate y modificar el campo para que concatene el valor viejo y el nuevo

Comment: @Benito-B Hola Benito, gracias por responder, manejo SQL Server y me gustaría poder hacerlo por código ya que la base de datos que estoy usando no es de mi poder. Si no que pertenece a otra persona

Comment: Entonces necesitarás primero leer lo que hay en el campo para poder concatenarlo, pues el `concat()` espera como parámetro todo lo que quieras concatenar, en tu caso el valor previo y el valor nuevo

Answer (score 0):

Una cosa que debes tener claro, es que si usas `update()` ya no debes usar `save()`.

Si usas `update()`:

Por lo que veo, lo que quieres adjuntar es un array, así que asumiré que esa columna `URLImg` contiene un array también.

```
$tramite = Tramite::findOrFail($RComunicInter_ID);
$tramite->update([
    'URLImg' => json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($tramite->URLImg, true), $data))
]);
```

La lógica principal radica aquí:

```
json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($tramite->URLImg, true), $data))
```

Primero debes obtener lo que tienes en base de datos, pero como es un `string`, debes convertirlo a un `array` utilizando [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
json_decode($tramite->URLImg, true)
```

Luego, utilizando [array_merge()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) unes el array que tienes en base de datos con el nuevo, pero como no puedes guardar arrays en una columna, ese nuevo array debes convertirlo a string utilizando [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Si usas `save()`, es la misma lógica:

```
$tramite = Tramite::findOrFail($RComunicInter_ID);
$tramite->URLImg = json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($tramite->URLImg, true), $data));
$tramite->save();
```

Si lo único que quieres es concatenar dos strings, simplemente utilizas el concatenador punto `(.)`.